# split data in nested json to make some calculations

Tags: python, nested-json

hoping someone helps me out. I have a nested json file and I'm trying to calculate the age difference between two lines of the file, the start_date and end_date with date format of mm/yyyy only. So I'm trying to split it so I can calculate the year difference between end_date and start_date, if over 10 years, I add to another list.

This is my code below, but it prints an empty list and I don't know how to fix it. Any tips or directions will be appreciated

Oh...I have to use default python libraries so even though pandas will be easier, I can't use it.

```
remove_card=[] 

def datebreakdown(data_file):
    expr1 = data_file['Credit Card']['start_date']
    expr2 = data_file['Credit Card']['end_date']
    breakdown1 = expr1.split('/') 
    breakdown2 = expr2.split('/')
    card_month = int(breakdown1[0]) - int(breakdown2[0])
    card_year= int(breakdown1[1]) - int(breakdown2[1])
    if card_year >= 10:
        return True
    elif card_year == 10 and card_year > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

for line in data_json: #data_json is name of the json file. 
    if datebreakdown(data_file) == True:
        remove_card.append(data_file)
```

Comment: Why doesn't your loop use `line`?

Comment: What do you mean by a "nested json file"?

Comment: the function never uses `card_month`.

Comment: `if card_year == 10 and card_year > 0:` There's no need for `card_year > 0` since `10 > 0`.

Comment: Since the first condition is `card_year >= 10`, the second condition will never be used, since `card_year == 10` is included in `card_year >= 10`.

Comment: @Barmar it does, there's a for loop at the bottom, ```for line in data_json```  didn't think it was necessary at the beginning.

Comment: Why is the loop needed at all? You're not doing anything with the line, and `data_file` is the same every time through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think these are the conditions you want:

```
    if card_year > 10:
        return True
    elif card_year == 10 and card_month > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The first condition should be strictly `>`, not `>=`. The second condition should compare the months when the year difference is exactly 10.

Another problem is that you're subtracting the dates in the wrong order. You're subtracting the end from the start, so it will always be negative. So those subtractions should be:

```
    card_month = int(breakdown2[1]) - int(breakdown1[0])
    card_year= int(breakdown2[1]) - int(breakdown1[1])
```

```
def datebreakdown(data_file):
    expr1 = data_file['Credit Card']['start_date']
    expr2 = data_file['Credit Card']['end_date']
    year1, month1 = expr1.split('/') 
    year2, month2 = expr2.split('/')
    start_date = int(year1) + int(month1)/12
    end_date = int(year2) + int(month2)/12
    return end_date - start_date > 10
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/8AVb5e)

Comment: it still prints an empty list, for both your codes and my codes (with your changes).

Comment: I've added a link to a working demo